# How to connect Debezium to MongoDB in Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, replication, debezium

I'm tinkering with streaming changes from MongoDB into Kafka using Debezium and encountering some sort of permission problem when Debezium attempts to access the MongoDB replica set.

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services: 

    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        hostname: mongodb
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - ./mongodb/data/admin:/data/admin
            - ./mongodb/data/keyfile:/data/keyfile
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
        command: --bind_ip_all --keyFile /data/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile --replSet rs0

    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.1
        hostname: zookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper
        ports:
            - 2181:2181
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
            ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.1.1
        hostname: kafka
        container_name: kafka
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
            - 9101:9101
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
            KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
            KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
            KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
            KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
            KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
            CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
            CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
            CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: "true"
            CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: anonymous

    schema-registry:
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.1
        hostname: schema-registry
        container_name: schema-registry
        depends_on:
            - kafka
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        environment:
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
            SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

    connect:
        image: tcgplayer/cp-kafka-connect:6.1.1-debezium-mongodb-1.5.0
        build:
            context: ./connect
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        hostname: connect
        container_name: connect
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - schema-registry
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
        environment:
            CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
            CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
            CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
            CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
            CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
            CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
            CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
            CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
            CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
            CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
            CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
            CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.1.1.jar
            CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
            CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
            CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
            CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

    control-center:
        image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.1.1
        hostname: control-center
        container_name: control-center
        depends_on:
            - kafka
            - schema-registry
            - connect
        ports:
            - 9021:9021
        environment:
            CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
            CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: connect:8083
            CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
            CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
            CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
            CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
            PORT: 9021
```

All the containers start up fine.  I can connect to MongoDB using Compass and the admin account.  I can also initialize the replica set via the mongo CLI.

#### docker exec

```
docker exec mongodb bash -c 'mongo -u admin -p admin < /data/admin/replica.js'
```

#### replica.js

```
config = {
    "_id": "rs0",
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "host": "mongodb:27017"
        }
     ]
}

rs.initiate(config)
```

But after I create the Debezium connector, it throws an exception when attempting to read the replica set.

#### POST to Connect REST API

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @debezium-mongodb.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

#### debezium-mongodb.json

```
{
    "name": "debezium-mongodb",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "mongodb.name": "mongodb",
        "mongodb.hosts": "rs0/mongodb:27017",
        "mongodb.user": "admin",
        "mongodb.password": "admin"
    }
}
```

#### Exception

```
[2021-05-10 19:04:21,453] ERROR Error while attempting to sync 'rs0.config.system.sessions':  (io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbSnapshotChangeEventSource)
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on config to execute command { find: "system.sessions", filter: {}, $db: "config", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1620673459, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 9B0A6379ED7BA2DF94F20FCA8AAE76877067E3D6), keyId: 6960734006342057988 } }, lsid: { id: UUID("e8418d9a-0f05-4c8c-9c34-a8a806183fe4") }, $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }' on server mongodb:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming up because the mongodb user doesn't have required privileges to read the data from config database.

For reading data from mongodb oplog:
"You must also have a MongoDB user that has the appropriate roles to read the admin database where the oplog can be read. Additionally, the user must also be able to read the config database in the configuration server of a sharded cluster and must have listDatabases privilege action."

Quoting it from Official Debezium Documentation